# Как преобразовать дамп массива в его структуру?

Tags: php

Можно ли преобразовать дамп массива обратно в массив? Например, с помощью print_r() я получаю дамп:

```
Array
(
    [key_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => str 1
            [1] => 30
            [2] => text
        )

    [key_2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 38
            [3] => 41
        )

)
```

Этот дамп нужно преобразовать к такому виду:

```
Array
(
    'key_1' => Array
        (
            0 => 'str 1',
            1 => 30,
            2 => 'text',
        ),

    'key_2' => Array
        (
            0 => 10,
            1 => 20,
            2 => 38,
            3 => 41,
        ),

)
```

То есть, что бы можно было просто скопировать преобразованный дамп, сохранить в переменную и получить готовую структуру массива.

Comment: вы лучше например вместо `print_r` используйте `var_export`. Если такое возможно, конечно, в вашем случае.

Comment: @teran знаю про `var_export()`, но она не подходит, т.к. дамп приходит уже с такой структурой.

Comment: есть готовые решения в англ.версии вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025909/how-create-an-array-from-the-output-of-an-array-printed-with-print-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать решить с помощью регулярных выражений. Например, дамп массива сохранить в строковой переменной:

```
$input = 'Array
(
    [key_1] => Array
        (
            [key_1] => str 1
            [1] => 30.g
            [2] => text text
        )

    [key_2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 20,r
            [2] => 38/1
            [3] => 41.1
        )

)';
```

И обработать эту переменную в `preg_replace()`:

```
$patt = [
    '~\[(\d+)]~',
    '~\[(.+)]|(?<==>\s)(?!Array)(.+)(?!$)~um',
    "~'(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)'~",
    '~(?<==>\s)(?!Array)(.+)(?!$)~m',
    '~(?<=\))(?!$)~m'
];

$repl = ['$1', "'\$1\$2'", '$1', '$1,', ','];
$output = preg_replace($patt, $repl, $input);

echo '<pre>', $output, '</pre>';
```

Полученную в результате обработки строку вида:

```
Array
(
    'key_1' => Array
        (
            'key_1' => 'str 1',
            1 => '30.g',
            2 => 'text text',
        ),

    'key_2' => Array
        (
            0 => 10,
            1 => '20,r',
            2 => '38/1',
            3 => 41.1,
        ),

)
```

Можно сохранить в переменную:

```
$arr = Array
(
    'key_1' => Array
        (
            'key_1' => 'str 1',
            1 => '30.g',
            2 => 'text text',
        ),

    'key_2' => Array
        (
            0 => 10,
            1 => '20,r',
            2 => '38/1',
            3 => 41.1,
        ),

);
```

И работать с ней, как с массивом:

```
var_dump($arr);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=2)
  'key_1' => 
    array (size=3)
      'key_1' => string 'str 1' (length=5)
      1 => string '30.g' (length=4)
      2 => string 'text text' (length=9)
  'key_2' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => int 10
      1 => string '20,r' (length=4)
      2 => string '38/1' (length=4)
      3 => float 41.1
```